# Scala, play framework: How to properly inject dependency in domain (entity) class

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection

I have an domain object:

```
case class User(val id: Long, username: String)
```

I don't want to follow service-repository approach (like typical spring applications, where entities are just data holders), I want to put functionality related to user into User object.

But I don't want to tie User object to concrete infrastructure implementations, so I want to pass interfaces (traits) instead.

I'm trying do this by following way:

```
case class User(val id: Long, val username: String, implicit val userRepository: IUserRepository)
```

And somewhere in application (controller, or somewhere else), I want to inject (with @Inject()) concrete implementation of IUserRepsoitory and want it to implicitly passed to constructor of User.

**Question 1**:
case class User(val id: Long, val username: String, **implicit val userRepository: IUserRepository**) - this doesn't work, it is not compiled

**Question 2**:
Is it correct approach to decouple infrastructure implementation from object domain in play? are they some best practices?

Thanks.

Comment: That's subjective, but for Q2 I would generally say "no", the domain object should not know how the application is managing it, according the context.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it bad practice if User (domain object) interacts with repository interface? (not implementation)

Comment: For me yes that's a bad

Comment: Why? Do you prefer entities to be just data holder? Just I'd like follow ddd approach (not 100%), more OO approach.. Why is it bad?

Comment: For me, case class are designed to represent data, not process

Comment: Ok, what if it regular class, is it good practice  to have reference to repository interface? Are there some pitfalls?

Comment: If the class represent a process it can make sense, otherwise for me it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

An entire parameter list is either implicit or not. You're looking for

```
case class User(id: Long, username: String)(implicit userRepository: IUserRepository)
```

Architecturally, it sounds like a bad idea to have a user class know it's own repository.

Comment: Ok, let's name it UserDao. I want do something like this: user->activate(), but not like: user->status = "active"; userService->update(user); Both interact with repository (dao) interfaces. What's bad in first case?